# WPF: Making an element not appear as public or friend?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio

In the designer, how can I (for instance) make a button be private within the Window that it is on? I remember a way to do this in Windows Forms, but I don't know how in WPF.

Is there a way to do it through Visual Studio?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using

```
<Button x:FieldModifier="private" />
```

On your object element.

This doesn't appear to be baked right into the designer where you can just edit it in the Properties Editor. You'll have to add this to the markup yourself. However, it is supported so at least you can get intellisense to help you put it there.